# sass percentage of a number

Tags: sass, percentage

I am stuck here.
I want to calculate 2/3 of 10rem like this:

```
$percentage : percentage(2/3); // 66.666667%
$width      : 10rem;
$calculate  : do magic: 66.666667% of 10rem;
 
img { max-height: calc( 100vh - $calculate ); }
```

I have been looking in the SASS documentation. I can only find some stuff about math function and not too much about percentage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `percentage(2/3)` function call appends a `%`. You can not multiply that with a non-unitless value like `10rem`. Instead, calculate it directly like:

```scss
img { 
    max-height: calc(100vh - #{2/3 * 10rem});
}
```

The `#{}` (interpolation) is needed to render the result of the calculation inside the Css `calc()` expression.

Read more on...

- Sass interpolation: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/interpolation
- Operators: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/operators/numeric